# UITextView's background like that of the Notes app in ipad/iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uitextview

I would like my UITextView background to repeat vertically (except for the top-margin), just like the Notes app in iphone/ipad, just like using repeat-y option in css.... Is that possible? How? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find technique you can use to implement Notes-like UI described in this [blog post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/03/stuff-you-learn-from-reverse-engineering-notes-app/).

Comment: I 'm not looking for all those features... just want a fixed-font editable textbox with repeating background.. I heard of the stretchableimagewithleftcapwidth method of the UIImage... how can I use it in this case?

Comment: @hkproj, read the article carefully - it describes exactly how to implement scrollable repeating background. I don't think stretchableImage will help you with that